# Inout parameter in async callback does not work as expected

Tags: swift

I'm trying to insert functions with `inout` parameter to append data received from async callback to an outside array. However, it does not work. And I tried everything I know to find out why - with no luck.

As advised by @AirspeedVelocity, I rewrote the code as follows to remove unnecessary dependencies. I also use an `Int` as the `inout` parameter to keep it simple.
The output is always:
`c before: 0`
`c after: 1`

I'm not able to figure out what goes wrong here.

```
func getUsers() {
    let u = ["bane", "LiweiZ", "rdtsc", "ssivark", "sparkzilla", "Wogef"]
    var a = UserData()
    a.userIds = u
    a.dataProcessor()
}

struct UserData {
    var userIds = [String]()
    var counter = 0
    mutating func dataProcessor() -> () {
        println("counter: \(counter)")
        for uId in userIds {
            getOneUserApiData(uriBase + "user/" + uId + ".json", &counter)
        }
    }
}

func getOneUserApiData(path: String, inout c: Int) {
    var req = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)
    var config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
    var session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(req) {
        (data: NSData!, res: NSURLResponse!, err: NSError!) in
        println("c before: \(c)")
        c++
        println("c after: \(c)")
        println("thread on: \(NSThread.currentThread())")
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to reduce your code to a much simpler case (preferably without using external libraries) and post it as part of the question. You probably won't get a good answer from anyone if they have to read through several pages of code to get what you're trying to do.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Thanks. I'll revise it asap.

Comment: I just posted a question to learn the way to make the modification work. It's a further question I have after knowing inout would not work in this case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254254/how-to-modify-a-value-with-nested-closures

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sad to say, modifying `inout` parameter in async-callback is meaningless.

From [the official document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html):

> Parameters can provide default values to simplify function calls and can be passed as in-out parameters, which modify a passed variable **once the function has completed its execution**.
>
> ...
>
> An in-out parameter has a value that is passed in to the function, is modified by the function, and is **passed back** out of the function to replace the original value.

Semantically, in-out parameter is not ["call-by-reference"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference), but ["call-by-copy-restore"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_copy-restore).

In your case, `counter` is write-backed only when `getOneUserApiData()` returns, not in `dataTaskWithRequest()` callback.

Here is what happened in your code

1. at `getOneUserApiData()` call, the value of `counter` `0` copied to `c`<sub>1</sub>
2. the closure captures `c`<sub>1</sub>
3. call `dataTaskWithRequest()`
4. `getOneUserApiData` returns, and the value of - unmodified - `c`<sub>1</sub> is write-backed to `counter`
5. repeat 1-4 procedure for `c`<sub>2</sub>, `c`<sub>3</sub>, `c`<sub>4</sub> ...
6. ... fetching from the Internet ...
7. callback is called and `c`<sub>1</sub> is incremented.
8. callback is called and `c`<sub>2</sub> is incremented.
9. callback is called and `c`<sub>3</sub> is incremented.
10. callback is called and `c`<sub>4</sub> is incremented.
11. ...

As a result `counter` is unmodified :(

---

Detailed explaination

Normally, `in-out` parameter is passed by reference, but it's just a result of compiler optimization. When closure captures `inout` parameter, "pass-by-reference" is **not safe**, because the compiler cannot guarantee the lifetime of the original value. For example, consider the following code:

```
func foo() -> () -> Void {
    var i = 0
    return bar(&i)
}

func bar(inout x:Int) -> () -> Void {
    return {
        x++
        return
    }
}

let closure = foo()
closure()
```

In this code, `var i` is freed when `foo()` returns. If `x` is a reference to `i`, `x++` causes access violation. To prevent such race condition, Swift adopts "call-by-copy-restore" strategy here.

Comment: Thank you both for such nice answers. I wrote my reason to pick yours as comment under the other answer.

Comment: Great answer, but disappointing. Is there a different way we could structure the OP's example to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 7):

Essentially it looks like you’re trying to capture the “inout-ness” of an input variable in a closure, and you can’t do that – consider the following simpler case:

```
// f takes an inout variable and returns a closure
func f(inout i: Int) -> ()->Int {
    // this is the closure, which captures the inout var
    return {
        // in the closure, increment that var
        return ++i
    }

}

var x = 0
let c = f(&x)

c() // these increment i
c()
x   // but it's not the same i
```

At some point, the variable passed in ceases to be `x` and becomes a copy.  This is probably happening at the point of capture.

edit: @rintaro’s answer nails it – `inout` is not in fact semantically pass by reference

If you think about it this makes sense.  What if you did this:

```
// declare the variable for the closure
var c: ()->Int = { 99 }

if 2+2==4 {
    // declare x inside this block
    var x = 0
    c = f(&x)
}

// now call c() - but x is out of scope, would this crash?
c()
```

When closures capture variables, they need to be created in memory in such a way that they can stay alive even after the scope they were declared ends.  But in the case of `f` above, it can’t do this – it’s too late to declare `x` in this way, `x` already exists.  So I’m guessing it gets copied as part of the closure creation.  That’s why incrementing the closure-captured version doesn’t actually increment `x`.

Comment: I upvoted both answers since they are all great. However, I can only choose one as the accepted answer. I'll pick the one by @rintaro since it's closer to the context (sample code) and it came with the detailed explanation. BTW, thanks for your blogs. I've read them many times and learned a lot from them.

Comment: No hard feelings @rintaro’s was a better answer :-)

Comment: This is the answer for actually getting things done. It is a nice workaround. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar goal and ran into the same issue where results inside the closure were not being assigned to my global inout variables. @rintaro did a great job of explaining why this is the case in a previous answer.

I am going to include here a generalized example of how I worked around this. In my case I had several global arrays that I wanted to assign to within a closure, and then do something each time (without duplicating a bunch of code).

```
// global arrays that we want to assign to asynchronously
var array1 = [String]()
var array2 = [String]()
var array3 = [String]()

// kick everything off
loadAsyncContent()

func loadAsyncContent() {

    // function to handle the query result strings
    // note that outputArray is an inout parameter that will be a reference to one of our global arrays
    func resultsCallbackHandler(results: [String], inout outputArray: [String]) {

        // assign the results to the specified array
        outputArray = results

        // trigger some action every time a query returns it's strings
        reloadMyView() 
    }

    // kick off each query by telling it which database table to query and
    // we're also giving each call a function to run along with a reference to which array the results should be assigned to
    queryTable("Table1") {(results: [String]) -> Void in resultsCallbackHandler(results, outputArray: &self.array1)}
    queryTable("Table2") {(results: [String]) -> Void in resultsCallbackHandler(results, outputArray: &self.array2)}
    queryTable("Table3") {(results: [String]) -> Void in resultsCallbackHandler(results, outputArray: &self.array3)}
}

func queryTable(tableName: String, callback: (foundStrings: [String]) -> Void) {

    let query = Query(tableName: tableName)
    query.findStringsInBackground({ (results: [String]) -> Void in

        callback(results: results)
    })
}

// this will get called each time one of the global arrays have been updated with new results
func reloadMyView() {

    // do something with array1, array2, array3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@rintaro perfectly explained why it doesn't work, but if you really want to do that, using UnsafeMutablePointer will do the trick:

```
func getOneUserApiData(path: String, c: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>) {
    var req = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)
    var config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.ephemeralSessionConfiguration()
    var session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(req) {
        (data: NSData!, res: NSURLResponse!, err: NSError!) in
        println("c before: \(c.memory)")
        c.memory++
        println("c after: \(c.memory)")
        println("thread on: \(NSThread.currentThread())")
    }

    task.resume()
}
```