# Mutate inout function paramter inside async block

Tags: ios, swift, closures, swift-playground

I have the following playground code:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

class A {

    var arr : [UIImage] = []

    func addItem(inout localArr: [UIImage]) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            localArr.append(UIImage())
            print("from inside function localArr: \(localArr)")
            print("form inside function: \(self.arr)")
        }
    }
}

let a = A()
a.addItem(&a.arr)
print("instant print :\(a.arr)")

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
    print("print after delay: \(a.arr)")
}

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

The output is:

```
instant print :[]
from inside function localArr: [<UIImage: 0x7f99e8706f10>, {0, 0}]
form inside function: []
print after delay: []
```

My question is, why is `localArr` not the same as `self.arr` inside the `addItem` and not the same as `a.arr` outside? My expectation was that when I pass the parameter as `inout` I should be able to operate on the actual object, not the copy, but clearly this is not what happens.

Edit: So thanks to dfri answer I know why this doesn't work. The `inout` is really [call-by-copy-restore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_copy-restore), check another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28252105/703809). Now, any suggestion on how to actually make the closure to capture the reference to the original object? Or perhaps I should use other technique to achieve what I want?

Comment: your code and output do not match..please edit them

Comment: Edited, one print statement was missing from inside the `addItem` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some theory on the `inout` keyword, see the following answer:

- [When to use inout parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486052/when-to-use-inout-parameters/34486250#34486250)

> **Do not depend on the behavioral differences between copy-in copy-out
>   and call by reference.**
>
> ...
>
> **When the function returns, your changes to the original are
>   overwritten with the value of the copy**. Do not depend on the
>   implementation of the call-by-reference optimization to try to keep
>   the changes from being overwritten.

Now, your `addItem` function will finish its call immediately and hence complete the `inout` copy-in/copy-out task prior to the delayed dispatch in the function. This makes it inherently bad to use delayed dispatches *within* a method of `inout` parameters, at least if the delay is one that tries to mutate the `inout` parameter.

To see this, lets track the references (rather than tracking the values) of some array, and how they possibly show mutation of the array during the runtime of our example.

```
func foo(inout bar: [Int]) {
    var pBar : UnsafePointer<Int> = UnsafePointer(bar)
    print("2: \(pBar)")
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        pBar = UnsafePointer(bar)
        print("3: \(pBar)")
        bar[0] = 2
        pBar = UnsafePointer(bar)
        print("4: \(pBar)")
    }
}

var a : [Int] = [1]
var pA : UnsafePointer<Int> = UnsafePointer(a)
print("1: \(pA)")
foo(&a)
print("foo call to a finished, a = \(a)")

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
    print("value of a naturally not changed here = \(a)")
    pA = UnsafePointer(a)
    print("5: \(pA)")
}

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

The output is quite self-explanatory:

```
1: 0x00007fe19271e930
2: 0x00007fe19271e930
foo call to a finished, a = [1] <-- call to foo finished, 'inout' procedure complete
3: 0x00007fe19271e930           <-- dispatch in `foo` starts
4: 0x00007fe1927085e0           <-- mutates 'bar': 'bar' copied (and never 
                                    "returned" as this step is already finished)
value of a naturally not changed here = [1]
5: 0x00007fe19271e930           <-- naturally 'a' wont see the effect of the
                                    delayed mutation in foo
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, this really helps to understand the `inout`. Do you have any suggestions on how to actually be able to mutate the array (or any other passed object) inside the delayed block?

Comment: @lawicko Happy to help. I have to leave for some hours, but I can look at it when I get back, given that no one else have helped you by then.

Comment: @lawicko use a reference type. I believe NSArray will do

Answer (score 1):

Swift Arrays are value types. Which always copy on assign.
Use NSMutableArray if you want to reference the original array.
Then there is also no need for `inout`

```
class A {

    var arr : NSMutableArray = []

    func addItem(localArr: NSMutableArray) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            localArr.addObject(UIImage())
            print("from inside function localArr: \(localArr)")
            print("form inside function: \(self.arr)")
        }
    }
}

let a = A()
a.addItem(a.arr)
print("instant print :\(a.arr)")

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
    print("print after delay: \(a.arr)")
}
```

print:

```
instant print :(
)
from inside function localArr: (
    "<UIImage: 0x7ffe1872b5f0>, {0, 0}"
)
form inside function: (
    "<UIImage: 0x7ffe1872b5f0>, {0, 0}"
)
print after delay: (
    "<UIImage: 0x7ffe1872b5f0>, {0, 0}"
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have upvoted your comment as the NSMutableArray indeed works in this case. However dfri answer actually explained the original question, which was why the the original code didn't work.

Comment: @lawicko I know ;) I was just trying to help you out while dfri was at work.