# How can I change an inout parameter from within a escaping closure?

Tags: swift, closures

I was trying to modify a parameter of function from within a escaping closure as below:

```
var completion = [()->Void]()

func addCompletion(closure: @escaping ()->Void) {
    completion.append(closure)
}

func testAdd(v: inout Int) {
    addCompletion{
        v = 1  // Compiler tells 'Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter 'v'
        print("hello1 \(v)")
    }
}

var x = 0
testAdd(v:&x)

for comp in completion {
    comp()
}
```

I was wondering if there is another way to let escaping closure change surrounding variable (as function's inout parameter), besides making it into reference type as a class object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inout` is specified to have a "copy-in copy-out" behaviour. The value of `x` is copied when you call the function. In the function body, the copy of `x` can be modified, or whatever. Then, when the function returns, the copy is copied again, and assigned to the original `x`. "Call-by-reference" could happen *as an optimisation*.

This explains why you can't modify an `inout` parameter in an escaping closure. The swift compiler can't possibly know when every escaping closure returns, to copy the modified value back.

You can use an actual pointer:

```
func testAdd(v: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>) {
    addCompletion{
        v.pointee = 1 // you just need to change all references to "v" to "v.pointee"
        print("hello1 \(v.pointee)")
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't like pointers, you can also do this trick (adapted from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62658325/5133585)):

```
func testAdd(modifyV: @escaping ((inout Int) -> Void) -> Void) {
    addCompletion{
        modifyV { v in // here you can change v however you like!
            v = 1
            print("hello1 \(v)")
        }
    }
}
```

You just need to change the caller to:

```
testAdd { $0(&x) }
```

Comment: Both work, thanks. Second solution in my opinion wraps modification by another closure which can be reference type, it really takes me quite while to comprehend.