Modify state variables from onTapGesture in a generic func
I have repetitive code for survey steps that I'm trying to make reusable:
private var workoutTypeSection: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        header("What Is Your Preferred Workout?")
        
        ForEach(WorkoutType.allCases) { workoutType in
            Text(workoutType.rawValue)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.purple)
                .frame(height: 55)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(selectedWorkoutTypes.contains(workoutType) ?
                            Color.blue : Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .onTapGesture {
                    workoutButtonPressed(workout: workoutType)
                }
        }
    }
    .padding(30)
}

private var bodyPartSection: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        header("Select a Body Part to Strengthen:")
        
        ForEach(BodyPart.allCases) { bodyPart in
            Text(bodyPart.rawValue)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.purple)
                .frame(height: 55)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(selectedBodyParts.contains(bodyPart) ?
                            Color.blue : Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .onTapGesture {
                    bodyPartButtonPressed(part: bodyPart)
                }
        }
    }
    .padding(30)
}

OnTapGesture selects or deselects survey options:
func workoutButtonPressed(workout: WorkoutType) {
    if selectedWorkoutTypes.contains(workout) {
        if let index = selectedWorkoutTypes.firstIndex(of: workout) {
            selectedWorkoutTypes.remove(at: index)
        }
    } else {
        selectedWorkoutTypes.append(workout)
    }
}

func bodyPartButtonPressed(part: BodyPart) {
    if selectedBodyParts.contains(part) {
        if let index = selectedBodyParts.firstIndex(of: part) {
            selectedBodyParts.remove(at: index)
        }
    } else {
        selectedBodyParts.append(part)
    }
}

where
@State var selectedWorkoutTypes: [WorkoutType] = []
@State var selectedBodyParts: [BodyPart] = []

and enum types are:
enum WorkoutType: String, CaseIterable, Codable, Identifiable {
case yoga = "Yoga"
case mobility = "Mobility"
case strength = "Strength"
case cardio = "Cardio" 

var id: WorkoutType { self }}

enum BodyPart: String, CaseIterable, Codable, Identifiable {
case legs = "Legs"
case core = "Core/Abs"
case back = "Back"
case chest = "Chest/Arms"
case neck = "Neck/Shoulders"
case body = "Whole Body"

var id: BodyPart { self }}

I created a generic function that makes the code reusable:
func surveyStepOptions<T : Identifiable & Hashable & CaseIterable & RawRepresentable >(_ enumType: T.Type, selected: [T])
-> some View
where T.RawValue == String
{
    ForEach(Array(enumType.allCases)) {option in
        
        Text(option.rawValue).font(.headline)
            .foregroundColor(.purple)
            .frame(height: 55)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(selected.contains(option) ?
                        Color.blue : Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .onTapGesture {
                if selected.contains(option) {
                    if let index = selected.firstIndex(of: option) {
                        selected.remove(at: index)
                    }
                } else {
                    selected.append(option)
                }
            }
    }
}

I struggle with changing state variables in onTapGesture because it says "selected" param is unmutable, but when I make it mutable it says that I can't use inout in the escaping closure. How to fix it?

Check please this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65538260/14015376

It would be helpful if you adapted your code to be reproducible and maybe include a screenshot or a mockup of the interface. As it stands, I find this approach far more complicated that it may need to be. It seems like you're allowing user to select, but you're not using any pickers? If so, is there a reason for that?

You are almost there, you just have to change the argument to a Binding so you can alter the selection from within the ForEach function
@ViewBuilder func surveyStepOptions<EnumType>(selected: Binding<[EnumType]>) -> some View where EnumType: CaseIterable & RawRepresentable<String> & Equatable{
    ForEach(Array(EnumType.allCases), id:\.rawValue) {option in
        
        Text(option.rawValue).font(.headline)
            .foregroundColor(.purple)
            .frame(height: 55)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(selected.wrappedValue.contains(option) ?
                        Color.blue : Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .onTapGesture {
                if let index = selected.wrappedValue.firstIndex(of: option) {
                        selected.wrappedValue.remove(at: index)
                } else {
                    selected.wrappedValue.append(option)
                }
            }
    }
}

Notice I also removed the explicit type argument, it isn't needed in Swift.
Here is the full code.
import SwiftUI

struct ReusableEnumParentView: View {
    @State var selectedWorkoutTypes: [WorkoutType] = []
    @State var selectedBodyParts: [BodyPart] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView{
            LazyVStack {
                workoutTypeSection
                bodyPartSection
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder var workoutTypeSection: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            header("What Is Your Preferred Workout?")
            
            surveyStepOptions(selected: $selectedWorkoutTypes)
        }
        .padding(30)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder var bodyPartSection: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            header("What Is Your Preferred Workout?")
            
            surveyStepOptions(selected: $selectedBodyParts)
        }
        .padding(30)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder func header(_ title: String) -> some View {
        Text(title)
    }
    @ViewBuilder func surveyStepOptions<EnumType>(selected: Binding<[EnumType]>) -> some View where EnumType: CaseIterable & RawRepresentable<String> & Equatable{
        ForEach(Array(EnumType.allCases), id:\.rawValue) {option in
            
            Text(option.rawValue).font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.purple)
                .frame(height: 55)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(selected.wrappedValue.contains(option) ?
                            Color.blue : Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .onTapGesture {
                    if let index = selected.wrappedValue.firstIndex(of: option) {
                            selected.wrappedValue.remove(at: index)
                    } else {
                        selected.wrappedValue.append(option)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ReusableEnumParentView()
}

enum WorkoutType: String, CaseIterable, Codable, Identifiable {
    case yoga = "Yoga"
    case mobility = "Mobility"
    case strength = "Strength"
    case cardio = "Cardio"
    
    var id: WorkoutType { self }}

enum BodyPart: String, CaseIterable, Codable, Identifiable {
    case legs = "Legs"
    case core = "Core/Abs"
    case back = "Back"
    case chest = "Chest/Arms"
    case neck = "Neck/Shoulders"
    case body = "Whole Body"
    
    var id: BodyPart { self }
}


You put it all together nicely, good stuff! I've been wondering about this approach I've seen often in questions, where views are split into vars and functions instead of structs, as most Apple tutorials show. Is there a reason for it or does this way of going about it have a name?

struct is "better" because SwiftUi can understand more about the type so it can be more efficient. But ViewBuilder is ok for small stuff. I use them when I have views with lots of parts so I can picture the body easier in my head.  @AndreiG.

Alright, I see, thanks!

So, given this approach of the OP, how are you supposed to form new questions? By creating an enum with values for every question? Is that common?

@AndreiG. yup. Idk if it’s common but it is a great example of reusable code, especially if you put it in a struct.

Wouldn't you also have to create a separate state for each question/enum? I am just trying to wrap my mind around how reusable overall this would be? Wouldn't code need to be changed every time the questions change? Or are the states also supposed to be created dynamically based on the number of questions?

@AndreiG. it depends on the model, you will need a “source of truth” the array of selected items needs to go somewhere so you need a variable for every question that has as an answer an array of elements. But any Binding works no matter the source.

@loremipsum provided a perfect answer to your question which should definitely be the solution, but I wanted to show what I imagined as an approach when I initially saw your question.
Assuming this is to be a survey or questionnaire format with questions and multiple choices for an answer, I'd structure it as follows:

A model to define a question and the available answers
A dictionary to keep track of the selections for each question
A main view with a list and sections for each question
A row view for each answer to allow for styling if selected or not.
A method for the selection logic.

Here's the full code:
import SwiftUI

struct Question {
    let question: String
    let answers: [String]
}

struct MultipleChoiceView: View {
    let questions: [Question] = [
        Question(question: "What's your favorite workout?", answers: ["Yoga", "Mobility", "Strength", "Cardio"]),
        Question(question: "What are you focusing on?", answers: ["Legs", "Core/Abs", "Back", "Chest/Arms", "Neck/Shoulds", "Whole Body"]),
        Question(question: "What's your favorite fruit?", answers: ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Mango"]),
        Question(question: "What's your favorite color?", answers: ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow"]),
    ]
    
    // A dictionary to keep track of the selected answers for each question
    @State private var selections: [String: Set<String>] = [:]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(questions, id: \.question) { question in
                Section(header: Text(question.question)) {
                    ForEach(question.answers, id: \.self) { answer in
                        MultipleSelectionRow(
                            isSelected: selections[question.question]?.contains(answer) ?? false,
                            text: answer
                        ) {
                            toggleSelection(for: question.question, answer: answer)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Toggle the selection of an answer for a given question
    func toggleSelection(for question: String, answer: String) {
        if selections[question]?.contains(answer) == true {
            selections[question]?.remove(answer)
        } else {
            if selections[question] == nil {
                selections[question] = []
            }
            selections[question]?.insert(answer)
        }
    }
}

struct MultipleSelectionRow: View {
    var isSelected: Bool
    var text: String
    var action: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(text)
            Spacer()
            if isSelected {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
            action()
        }
    }
}

#Preview{
    MultipleChoiceView()
    
}



All you would have to do to adapt this is use the enum instead of String for the answers.
